# Accessing properties of second table via element of first table

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables which are in a relationship. They are called tblX and tblY.

```
var x = (from v in db.tblX select v).First();
```

Now x has these properties:

```
x.name
x.id
x.tblY
```

tblY has these properties: idY, nameY.

After I use the linq statement above, I can get to idY without making a join. I can access x.tblY.idY and x.tblY.nameY. Is it ok if I access them like this? Is it a good programming practise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tblY's properties will be loaded lazily. It is fine unless you do this operation repeteadly for big numbers of tblX objects. Than you might consider eager loading.

Related: [Entity Framework - what's the difference between using Include/eager loading and lazy loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505170/entity-framework-whats-the-difference-between-using-include-eager-loading-and)